# Cómo Guardar un array dentro de otro array lenguaje C++

Tags: c++, array

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente código el cuál es un función recursiva que obtiene todas las posibles soluciones para dibujar 8 reinas en un tablero de ajedrez sin que se maten entre si..

```
void reinas(int j) { //recursiva
     for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
       tablero[j]=i;
       if(validarTablero(j)==true) {
         if(j==7) {
           mostrarTablero();
       } else {
         reinas(j+1);
       }
     }
   }
  }
```

Lo que me gustaría sabes es como podría implementar para poder guardar cada solución el cuál es un array con las posiciones, dentro de otro array para así poder usar cada solución independientemente..

Comment: Probablemente quieras usar un [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) con elementos del mismo tipo que la variable `tablero`.

Answer (score 2):

> Lo que me gustaría sabes es como podría implementar para poder guardar cada solución el cuál es un array con las posiciones

Tienes muchas soluciones diferentes dependiendo de tus necesidades. Te las ordeno de menor gasto de memoria a mayor gasto de memoria:

1. **Una colección de índices**. Si consideramos que las 8<sup>2</sup> posiciones del tablero están numeradas de arriba abajo y de izquierda a derecha:

   ```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
    8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
   16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
   24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
   32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
   40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
   48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
   56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
   ```

   Puedes devolver una colección de datos que contenga índices. Por lo tanto esta sería una posible solución:

   ```
   std::uint8_t reina[8] { 3, 14, 18, 31, 33, 44, 48, 61 };
   ```
2. **Una colección de enteros de ocho bits sin signo**. Asumiendo que un entero de ocho bits sin signo representa una fila del tablero, y que un bit a `1` significa "*esta casilla no tiene reina*" y a `0` significa lo contrario, puedes devolver esta posible solución:

   ```
   bool tablero[8 * 8] { 0b00010000,
                         0b00000010,
                         0b00100000,
                         0b00000001,
                         0b01000000,
                         0b00001000,
                         0b10000000,
                         0b00000100 };
   ```
3. **Una colección de booleanos**. Asignando a cada casilla un valor booleano en que `false` significa "*esta casilla no tiene reina*" y `true` significa lo contrario, puedes devolver esta posible solución:

   ```
   bool tablero[8 * 8] { false, false, false,  true, false, false, false, false,
                         false, false, false, false, false, false,  true, false,
                         false, false,  true, false, false, false, false, false,
                         false, false, false, false, false, false, false,  true,
                         false,  true, false, false, false, false, false, false,
                         false, false, false, false,  true, false, false, false,
                          true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
                         false, false, false, false, false,  true, false, false };
   ```
4. **Dos colecciones de booleanos**. Siguiendo las premisas de `true` y `false` anteriores y siendo una de las colecciones una fila completa del tablero y otra una colección de filas, puedes devolver esta una posible solución:

   ```
   bool tablero[8][8] { {false, false, false,  true, false, false, false, false},
                        {false, false, false, false, false, false,  true, false},
                        {false, false,  true, false, false, false, false, false},
                        {false, false, false, false, false, false, false,  true},
                        {false,  true, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                        {false, false, false, false,  true, false, false, false},
                        { true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
                        {false, false, false, false, false,  true, false, false} };
   ```
5. **Una colección de coordenadas**. Teniendo un objeto coordenada:

   ```
   struct coordenada { std::uint8_t x = 0, y = 0; };
   ```

   Puedes devolver una colección de datos que contenga las coordenadas. Por lo tanto esta sería una posible solución:

   ```
   coordenada reina[8] { {0, 3}, {1, 6}, {2, 2}, {3, 7}, {4, 1}, {5, 4}, {6, 0}, {7, 5} };
   ```

Fíjate que he mencionado "*colecciones de datos*" no "*arrays*", esto es porque puedes elegir devolver los valores de diferentes maneras:

1. **Rellenar una formación**. Si pasas por referencia una formación, la puedes rellenar en tu función:

   ```
   using tablero = std::uint8_t[8];

   void reinas(int j, tablero &t);
   ```
2. **Rellenar un contenedor**. Si pasas por referencia un contenedor de datos, lo puedes rellenar en tu función:

   ```
   using tablero = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;

   void reinas(int j, tablero &t);
   ```

   En este caso los contenedores más adecuados serían `std::vector` o `std::array`, siendo el segundo mejor elección. La alternativa de colección de booleanos sería:

   ```
   using tablero = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>;

   void reinas(int j, tablero &t);
   ```
3. **Devolver un contenedor**. Puedes hacer los cálculos en la función y devolver el resultado:

   ```
   using tablero = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>;

   tablero reinas(int j);
   ```